# Android: How to implement an account login system?

Tags: android, authentication, accountmanager, auth-token

So far i followed this tutorial: http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/

It's working perfect. But now I want to force my users to login into my app.

Just a few issues I have and not have found a solution to, yet:

1. How should I handle usual on App start logins? The App starts, calls the MainActivity, which has no layout and just decides whether to call the AuthenticatorActivity or allow the user entrance to the app. That's my solution. Anyone having a better one?
2. When I invalidate the authToken of an account, the next time the user when the user triggers an action, which requires the authToken, the AuthenticatorActivity will be started. However if he just presses the back button, he can still return to using the App, of course he can not change anything as there is now authToken, but still it may confuse some users. How can I solve this in a better way?

Best Regards!

Comment: instead of  `AuthenticatorActivity` you can use dialog-box to authentication,But you will face some issue in cancel of alertbox.

Comment: I appriciate your comment, but a dialog-box is a design no-go imho.

Answer (score 2):

You should may be read more about [data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) .

You can override the Application class, and create your own MyApplication class (the singleton pattern), then you can:

- manage the first behaviour of the application when it is lunched.
- manage your token , because the context is accessible from every activity, and the context of this class is live whenever the Application is live. Then when the user is logged out, you delete the token from this class, and in each activity onCreat() you check if there is a token in the current Application context or not.
- you can override the onBackPressed() methode in the Authenticator activity , to check if he has a token or not:

  /*

  - *(non-Javadoc)
  - *@see android.app.Activity#onBackPressed()
    */

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
      // check if the user has a token or not before letting him go back

  ```
  if(hasToken()){ 
      // go back
      AuthenticatorActivity.super.onBackPressed();
  }
  else{
     // close the activity
     finish();
  ```

  }
  }
- you can use Shared preferences to save your cookies safely.
- you can also use a database if you have many data to save.

you can also use a launcher Activity, which starts the first and decides to which activity to redirect you : the Login Activity or the Main Activity.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain what you mean by managing the token? And also calling finish() does not close the application, only the activity, doesn't it?

Comment: yes it is closing only the Activity, sorry, I update it now, thank you for the correction. PS : Actually you can close the application by this way , if you navigate to the AuthenticatorActivity by closing the precedent activity...
by managing the token: storing the token as shared in all the application (and if you want save it in shared preferences or in a database, then you will save it even for next application starts).
Then you can access to the token : to read it or to save it, from everywhere.

Comment: I dont think saving the token yourself is good practice. This is what the AccountManagers getAuthToken should be used for imho!